# Embedding of matrices over a field extension

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $L/K$ be an extension of fields of degree $m$. Then $L^n$ is an $mn$-dimensional vector space over $K$. By considering multiplication by elements of $L$, we obtain an embedding $L \hookrightarrow M_{m}(K)$? How do we obtain an injective ring homomorphism $M_n(L)$ into $M_{mn}(K)$? Is it obtained by replacing each element of $L$ by an $m \times m $ matrix with entries in $K$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is how it is obtained.

More specifically, every element $a\in L$ can be seen as an $m$-tuple of $K^m$. Let us be explicit and denote this isomorphism $\phi : L \to K^m$.

As the map $L\to L$, $x\mapsto a\cdot x$ is $K$-linear, this identification also yields the embedding you mention in your question, which I will denote $\psi:L\to M_m(K)$.

In particular it follows that $\phi(ax) = \psi(a)(\phi(x))$

Let $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)\in L^n$ and $M\in M_n(L)$.
Then $(Mx)_i$ is given by $\sum_{j=1}^n M_{ij}x_j$.

Therefore we finally have
$$\phi((Mx)_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n \phi(M_{ij} x_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n \psi(M_{ij}) \phi(x_j) = \tilde M \phi(x)\,,$$
where $\phi(x)$ abusively denotes $(\phi(x_1), \dots, \phi(x_n))\in K^{mn}$ (where we identify $(K^m)^n\cong K^{mn}$) and $\tilde M\in M_{mn}(K)$ is the matrix $(\psi(M_{ij}))_{i,j}$ (where we identify $M_n(M_m(K))\cong M_{mn}(K)$).

In particular, the map $M\mapsto \tilde M$ yields an embedding $M_n(L)\subset M_{nm}(K)$.